# WinForms reportViewer (.NET 3.5) binding data from a DataTable

Tags: c#, data-binding, .net-3.5, datatable, reportviewer2008

WinForms reportViewer (.NET 3.5) binding data from a DataTable

I'm trying to bind a DataTable which is dynamically created, to a reportViewer control . There are many tutorials on this on the internet but they don't seem to work for this project... (there are related questions on stack overflow but the solutions don't work in my case)

This is the event handler for the Show Report Button:

```
    private void btn_ShowRwport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the date range for the report
        rptctn.SetDateRangeOne(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), dateTimePicker_Start.Value, dateTimePicker_End.Value);

        //Get the report datatable
        DataTable dt = rptctn.GetReportTest(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        //Set the datagridview
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        //Set the reportViewer
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();            
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

I know the DataTable is being retried properly as the dataGridView works...
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvZHpEYS1BWWhqZ3c/edit?usp=sharing

The project has the following constraints:

- Must use .NET 3.5 due to client environment. (so report viewer 2008)
- Creation of DataTable and the ReportViewer are in different packages (application/presentation layer)
- I'm trying to avoid creating .rdlc files as reports (DataTables) have a variable number of rows/columns.

Anyone know how i can bind a dynamicly created DataTable to a report viewer in my case?

Comment: Is your data source in the report the same name as `dt.TableName`?

Comment: @JoeyGennari i don't have a data source set to reportViewer1 (i thought that's what the above code does); also as i mentioned above i dont have any .rdlc files in the project, what would i set the data source to? 
dt.TableName's value is an empty string.

Comment: Really what you need to do is dynamically create a RDLC file and add a table. I found a 3rd party example with some code from http://www.gotreportviewer.com, just look down on the right hand side of the page for Generate RDLC dynamically - Table.

Comment: @JoeyGennari That will work, i just have to play around with it for a while. If you write up what you said above as an answer I'll mark it as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really what you're asking to do is dynamically create an RDLC file and add a table. I found a 3rd party example with some code from gotreportviewer.com, just look down on the right hand side of the page for Generate RDLC dynamically - Table.